# ViewPager is won't let touch the page

Tags: android, android-layout

Viewpager works when I use it inside `DrawerLayout`,but this time tab items disappear.It shows tabs when I use the code bellow but this time I can't enable any element inside the page.I can't switch between tabs and I can't scroll.I can only touch to Navigation menu.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".AnaEkran">





        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="Today Match">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Free" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Vip" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:id="@+id/f1bizim_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
                </FrameLayout>






    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/yan_menu">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>







    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.TabItem;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;


import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class AnaEkran extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private int soka = 4;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;

     FirebaseAuth mAuth;
     FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
     FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
     DatabaseReference dataref = database.getReference();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabdene);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);





        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));



        drawer = findViewById(R.id.f1bizim_content);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();







        if(user != null) {
            soka = 4;
        }else {
            soka = 7;
        }







    }//oncrate


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tabdene, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            if (position == 0){
                BlankFragment tab1 = new BlankFragment();
                return tab1;
            }
            if (position == 1 && soka == 7){
                logatlat tab2 = new logatlat();
                return tab2;
            }
            else if (position == 1 && soka == 4){
                BlankFragment2 tab2 = new BlankFragment2();
                return tab2;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

         //SectionsPagerAdapter.removeTabPage(position);

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "FREE";
                case 1:
                    return "PAID";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: make drawer layout as parent node and then coordinate layout try it

Comment: Is it shoulds like ...CoordinatorLayout->DrawerLayout->CoordinatorLayout ?

Comment: DrawerLayout---> then whole code in Coordinate Layout try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code Like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/f1bizim_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".AnaEkran">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="Today Match">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Free" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Vip" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"></FrameLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"

    app:headerLayout="@layout/activity_badminton"
    >

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

and plzzz change menu name and nav hear name according to you

Comment: Thank you it's work but there is white space appear on top.Also nav menu dissapear.Here is the ss.https://i.postimg.cc/x173gnVz/Screenshot-2019-02-13-15-51-18.png

Comment: in drawer layout remove margin top then white space will gone